# Can't spawn gameobjects in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void Spawnwave()
{
    //Standard unit is lvl1 unit
    int saverUnit = 1;
    int saverPossibilty = 100;
    System.Random randy = new System.Random();
    //This for gets the possibility for the first possible enemy
    for (int i = 0; i < possibilty.Length; i++)
    {
        if (possibilty[i] != 0)
        {
            saverUnit = i;
            saverPossibilty = possibilty[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    //As only 2 kind of units per wave can be spawned +1 spawns the "stronger" one
    for (int i = 0; i < level+5; i++)
    {
        if (randy.Next(100) > saverPossibilty)
        {
            StartCoroutine(SpawnUnit(saverUnit + 1));
        }
        else
        {
            StartCoroutine(SpawnUnit(saverUnit));
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator SpawnUnit(int unit)
{
    Instantiate(enemies[unit],spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenEnemies);
}
```

So I am trying to make a Unity Tower Defense game. These two methods should spawn 5+the value of the level enemies with an interval of .5 seconds. I debugged it and it runs through the code but I just do not get any new gameobjects.

I tried to look for resolutions on eg.: Youtube (brackeys) and his Tower Defense Tutorial but I still can not find my mistake.

Thanks for any help,
Mika.

Comment: You should never need to call `System.Random` in Unity, use the built in `UntityEngine.Random` instead.

Comment: I can't really see any problem with this code. `System.Random` is fine.

Comment: Did you look at the hierarchy will the game was running your objects​ might just be spawning at a different position then the one you are expecting.

Comment: As @CNuts says your game objects probably are in another coordinates, after you create them try to set the position of your new GameObject in to a place you know your camera can see them.

Comment: I don't see an issue with `System.Random` either: `System.Random` lets you *specify a seed value* which the `UnityEngine.Random` *does not.*  Specifying a seed value can be quite important sometimes!

Answer (score 0):

You should also being calling the Random Generation as follows as @ScottChamberlain suggested, 10 being an arbitrary number.

```
int rnd = Random.Range(0,10)
```

Although I am unable to test this currently my inital thoughts are that this line

```
Instantiate(enemies[unit],spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation);
```

Should be

```
GameObject clone = Instantiate(enemies[unit],spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation) as GameObject;
```

Finally, how are you doing your possibility array.

Comment: Storing the instantiated object in a variable is optional. It doesn't effect the instantitation at all.

Comment: my possibility array is an array of integers with values from 0-100. I have another array for all enemies. So if i have an enemy array with Length of 3 my Possibility array has the values {90,10,0} for example. Deciding by that integer i want to increase the chance of spawning better enemies as their possibility to spawn increases as the game goes. My could should just work fine, i think... But somehow the gameobjects do not spawn.

Comment: So you're using an array of integers to determine the spawn probability of an enemy.  Have you debugged that the co routines are actually getting called?